# Change label content in template using c# code doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some XAML code template (style) where I couldn't change lable (labelName) text using c# code. Tryed google but cannot find something specific. Looks like there is some small detail that I overlooked.

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemM" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="brd"  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <Grid  Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                <Label x:Name="labelName" Content="12345" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" Width="100" FontSize="20" Margin="40,25,0,0"/>
                                <Label Content="Price" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" Width="60" Height="40" FontSize="12" Margin="180,5,0,0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </RadioButton>
                </Border> 
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The c# code:

```
ListBoxItem item = new ListBoxItem();
item.Style = (Style)item.FindResource("ListBoxItemM");
/* Here the label is null, unfortunately */
Label nameLabel = (Label)item.Template.Resources.FindName("labelName");
nameLabel.Content = "98765";
MenuListBox.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: The Label's Content should be bound to the Content of the ListBoxItem: `<Label Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" .../>`. Then just bind the ListBox's ItemsSource to a collection of strings.

Comment: @Clemens thanks, but what if there are several labels in the Grid? Sorry, I've should added several items to the initial question. Added now one more label.

Comment: You should use a ContentPresenter instead of a Label. Then set the ListBox's ItemTemplate to a DataTemplate with elements that bind to different properties of the item type (i.e. a view model class with multiple properties).